# Why won't the Visual Studio Graphics Designer let me draw anything?

Tags: bitmap, visual-studio-2013

I have added a bitmap file to my project in VS2013. When I open it, the Visual Studio image editor shows up. I can draw on the image but as soon as I let the mouse button go, the drawed line/pattern/... will disappear and I end up with a white surface again.

The only workaround I can use: open the saved PNG with Paint, save it there and then it is suddenly editable in VS.

Is this a bug? Am I missing a setting that has to be enabled?

[image]

Comment: Hmm, hard to guess.  Maybe it is mad about having to run on a Mac with a pixel format that everybody stopped using 25 years ago.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks @HansPassant. And by the way: it does not matter which pixel format is selected.